# MySQL statements -- Pattern Matching etc

Tags: mysql

> display all rows where the hiredate is before april 1, 1981 and the
>   employee name is from A to S

This is the code that I have done and it doesn't work. :( When I tried to put `AND` between `'%A`' and `'%S'` it doesn't work either. :( When I deleted the `'%S'` it worked but it will only retrieve the record with a name starting with letter `A`. :(
Can you guys help? I really don't know what to do. :(

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE HIREDATE < '1981-04-1' 
 AND ENAME LIKE '%A' '%S'
```

Thanks. ^^

Comment: You want names starting with A-S? Or names ending with A-S? Or names starting with A **and** ending with S?

Answer (score 1):

You were close. I guess you want names **starting** from A, B, C, ... S (not ending in A-S). Right?

If yes, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE HIREDATE < '1981-04-01'    --- notice the  -01
  AND ENAME >= 'A' 
  AND ENAME < 'T'
```

Comment: another question again how about if the question is:
/*
Retrieve all columns from tblemployee where COMM is not null and (the first character of ENAME starts with A or the second character of ENAME is A)
*/
... ENAME LIKE 'A%' .. 
what will be my next syntax if the second character would be A?

Comment: for "the second character of ENAME is A", use: `ENAME LIKE '_A%'` The `_` is the special coding for **one character**. `%` means **any number of any characters**.

Comment: See also here for explanations of the two wildcard characters `%` and `_` used in `LIKE`: http://www.learn-sql-tutorial.com/SimpleSelects.cfm#h1.14

Comment: And this where you can practice, too: http://sqlzoo.net/ (but not many LIKE examples/questions)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE HIREDATE < '1981-04-01' AND SUBSTR ( ENAME, 1, 1 ) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'S'
```

Comment: This is correct but the index of `ENAME` cannot be used when a function, like `SUBSTR()` is called. So, the query will have to make a full scan (for all rows with hiredate before 1981-04-01.)

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE HIREDATE < '1981-04-1' AND ENAME REGEXP '^[a-s]+$'
```

**[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)**

Comment: it works but it must retrieve only from A-S :( when i tried it the name starting with W was retrieved also :(

Comment: I tested here ( name started with `w`) and it returns `0` i.e. working fine